# Using SSH Git: key lost after system restart?

Tags: ssh, git, key-authentication, github

I am setting up Git usage on Raspbian.
This worked OK:

```
   cd .ssh
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "name@asdf.com"
   eval $(ssh-agent -s)
   ssh-add ./id_rsa_rpi
```

After I created the keys locally, I went to GitHub and added a public key there.
It all worked OK, I cloned a few repositories without problems. Confirmed it all with `ssh -vT git@github.com`

However, after a shutdown yesterday and a powerup today, `git pull` didn't work:
`git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).`

I had to repeat the following:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add .ssh/id_rsa_rpi
```

Now it works again.

How do I make this permanent?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that as your key is not named with default name 'id_rsa', git has to know which one to use.

https://superuser.com/questions/232373/how-to-tell-git-which-private-key-to-use

Comment: Yes, according to the `ssh` manpage, The default is  ~/.ssh/id_dsa, ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa, ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 and ~/.ssh/id_rsa.  Ssh-agent is a process (daemon) which can manage keys, but as a process, dies when you reboot.